# Encontrando erro no meu css pelo NETBEANS

Tags: css, html5, bootstrap

O meu código esta apresentando o seguinte problema no css (MENSAGEM DE ERRO NA IMAGEM)[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o código com erro nao interfere e consigo rodar normalmente meu site mesmo com o erro no css.

```
@supports ((-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)) or (transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0))) {
  .carousel-item {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out, -o-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
            backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
            perspective: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Que problema? Você só postou um código CSS e uma imagem que tem exatamente o mesmo código.

Comment: sim ele esta indicando erro na primeira linha do código que esta em vermelho, e postei o código caso não de pra ver na imagem..

Comment: Se posicionar o *mouse* sobre o código em destaque, aparece alguma mensagem?

Comment: Token inesperado LPAREN localizado
Token inesperado WS localizado
Token inesperado LPAREN localizado
Token inesperado NUMBER localizado

----

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione esta informação. Aproveite e coloque qual editor está utilizando e se o código funciona ou não, apesar desta mensagem.

Comment: O css inteiro é muito grande? Se não por favor poste ele... Acredito que o erro esteja antes dessa linha

Comment: Oi Anderson! Verifiquei, não tem nenhum erro em si no código, o problema é que o netbeans não reconhece essa classe do bootstrap. Ao testar no notepad++ não mostrou nenhum erro. Obrigada pela resposta